# JavaScript / JQuery Double Execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am using the following code as a debug - I'm just trying to watch for clicks on radio buttons and style them appropriately.

```
$("#item-select-form label.radio").click(function() {
  var child_input, input_id;
  console.log("clicked!");
  child_input = $(this).children("input");
  input_id = child_input.attr("id");
  return console.log(input_id);
});
```

The code seems to be working fine.  I get the "clicked!" and I see the proper id of the child input.  However, this code is being executed twice, and I can't figure out why (I'm using Rails if that makes any difference).

How can I track down where and why it was called from?

Comment: Add a console.log() or a breakpoint before the function, and check if the handler is getting attached twice.

Comment: are you adding the `.click()` function multiple times? that would cause it to execute multiple times. check other parts of the source to see if you have that code duplicated

Comment: How do I use console.log to determine exactly WHERE the handler is getting attached?  All I can really do at this point is determine that it is, in fact, being called twice by tossing a `console.log("hi there!")` inside the javascript.

Answer (score 1):

This is almost certainly because the event is being bound multiple times. jQuery executes all bound event handlers.

To ensure that it is executed only once, you should bind it just once. *Or* you shoudl `unbind` any bound handlers before binding again. For ex:

```
// unbind the previously bound handler
$("#item-select-form label.radio").unbind('click');

// bind your click
$("#item-select-form label.radio").click(function() {
...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

if you're binding this event on an ajax response it will be triggered multiple times, you should unbind the event before binding it again(if there was no binding before it won't cause an error) also, there's an improvement in your code, you can either use this:

```
$("#item-select-form").find("label.radio").click...
```

or

```
$("#item-select-form").click(function(e){ 
    var elemPressed = $(e.target);
    if( elemPressed ).is("label.radio") ){
      //do your stuff
    }
});
```

both of these techniques are faster than your original selector (which uses [sizzle](http://www.myinkblog.com/sizzle-a-look-at-jquerys-new-css-selector-engine/)  ) and the second one ( my favorite ) let's you create just a single event for a whole section of the page instead of creating several events ( and thus, slowing down performance ) to the DOM

Comment: Thanks for the hints and code improvement!  I will take a look. I'm just confused because I'm not using any AJAX and I think this is the only JavaScript referencing this page....  Shouldn't be executing twice!!

Comment: I did get your code working (hopefully my JQuery will execute a bit faster!), but it is still executing twice.  How can I use the console to find out where these methods are being called from?

Comment: Well, this is strange, can you give some code or at least some html? My guess is that you're creating elements from an ajax response and bind the events to these elements, the beauty of the code i gave you is that you only need to bind the event to a element #item-select-form once ( maybe on a $(window).load ) and you're done, it will work even if no label.radio exists at page load.